# Checking if tree is BST

Tags: ruby, binary-search-tree

I wrote a code in ruby to check if tree passed in is a binary search tree. Just wanna check if I'm on the right track.

```
def checkBST(t) 
    return false if t==nil
   if t.left!=nil && t.left>t 
        return false
    end
    if t.right!=nil && t.right<t
        return false
    end
    if checkBST(t.left) && checkBST(t.right)
        return true
    end
end
```

Comment: Who says an empty tree (`t == nil`) is not a valid bst? Your base case seems incorrect to me. Moreover, this question as it stands needs to be elaborated on. What is the current _issue_ with the code? Be specific. Check out [ask]

Comment: what I meant was, this code is to check if the tree (with values in it) are arranged like a BST. I'm not very sure if my code works the way I want to and I wanna get more opinions, maybe how to make it more efficient or something?

Comment: SO is not a code-testing service. You are fully capable of running it and seeing if it works yourself. Make sure to check edge cases like multiple identical keys and empty trees. If it doesn't work, it'll give bad output or crash, not destroy the universe. Don't be afraid to run your code and just see if it works. If you're looking for code review, there's another SE site for that. If you have a specific problem, this is the place. And if you have an update or clarification for your question it is best to post it as an edit to the question rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain it line by line first :-

```
1    def checkBST(t) 
2        return false if t==nil
3       if t.left!=nil && t.left>t 
4            return false
5        end
6        if t.right!=nil && t.right<t
7            return false
8        end
9        if checkBST(t.left) && checkBST(t.right)
10            return true
11        end
12    end
```

Line 2 - return true when t is NULL.

Line 3 and 6 - you are juct checking the immediate child, what if child satisfy the BST property but not its grand children. Try yourself, you will get to know what i am trying to say.

Here is a probable solution - i am just writing it, did not compile, you can work on it more.

Function -

```
bool isBST(class tree* root, int minL, int maxR)
{
    if(!root)
        return true;
    else if(root->data > minL && root->data < maxR)
        return true;
    else if(root->data < minL || root->data > maxR)
        return false;
    return isBST(root->right, root->data, maxR) && isBST(root->left, minL, root->data);
}

Caller - 
isBST(root, INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
```